# jenkins start async "Spawning processes from build"

Tags: process, jenkins

Not sure where this code goes copied from https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Spawning+processes+from+build
Tried to put it in my config.xml of job

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<project>
  <actions/>
  <description>dont use now</description>
  <keepDependencies>false</keepDependencies>
  <properties/>
  <scm class="hudson.scm.NullSCM"/>
  <canRoam>true</canRoam>
  <disabled>false</disabled>
  <blockBuildWhenDownstreamBuilding>false</blockBuildWhenDownstreamBuilding>
  <blockBuildWhenUpstreamBuilding>false</blockBuildWhenUpstreamBuilding>
  <triggers/>
  <concurrentBuild>false</concurrentBuild>
  <builders>
    <hudson.tasks.BatchFile>
      <command>\work\s1.bat</command>
    </hudson.tasks.BatchFile>

    <scriptdef name="get-next-minute" language="beanshell">
  <attribute name="property" />

  date = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm")
    .format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 60000));
  project.setProperty(attributes.get("property"), date);
</scriptdef>

<get-next-minute property="next-minute" />
<exec executable="at">
  <arg value="${next-minute}" />
  <arg value="/interactive" />
  <arg value="\work\start.bat" />
</exec>
  </builders>
  <publishers/>
  <buildWrappers/>
</project>
```

But now the job does not come up in the UI (edited above on notepad++)

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

- Restart Jenkins

or

- Go in "Manage Jenkins" > "Reload Configuration from Disk"

Hope that helps

Comment: No my question is how/ where do I put that code? Is it part of config.xml or part of an ant script called from jenkins. I know how to get rid of a job folder /reset it. what i want to know is how the code in my question.